# Selenium send keys not working on upload button

Tags: selenium

I am trying to upload a file using selenium send keys, but not working, .In my case button name is Attach Sign Off , its not working for it. Please help

```html
<form class="v-upload v-widget v-upload-immediate" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="https://gbl04115.systems.uk.hsbc:8571/DSLWeb/APP/UPLOAD/2/921/action/3305f203-9e0c-4213-aecd-6ee2b2b29eb1" target="921_TGT_FRAME">
<div aria-describedby="gwt-uid-2">
<input type="hidden"/>
<input class="gwt-FileUpload" type="file" name="921_file" aria-describedby="gwt-uid-2"/>
<div class="v-button" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-hidden="false" aria-describedby="gwt-uid-2">
<span class="v-button-wrap">
<span class="v-button-caption">Attach Sign-off</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Hi @AutoMater where is your button id and name that is uploading your codes.

Comment: sorry , I didnt get you

Comment: i mean how can i get your button element id or name. eg <button id="btnSave" name="Save"> </button>.

Comment: what is the `browse` button? `browse` and `Attach Sign Off` is the same button?

Comment: what code you are tying?

Comment: @Anderson , browse is a separate button which works fine with send keys, but Attach sign off doesnt work

Comment: @JarYit  by using this <span class="v-button-caption">Attach Sign-off</span>

Comment: @Shubham I have used  getElement("Xpath of Attach sign Off button").sendKeys(file path) ,

Comment: For sendKeys to upload to work the tag should be input and its type attribute should be text

Comment: @AutoMater, `span` with text `Attach Sign-off` not seem to be the target element. Provide more `HTML` code to define real upload button

Comment: @Mrunal i think Type= "file" should also work , but not working

Comment: @AutoMater - Could you please update tag here with particular code you are using here also please provide code that you wrote to make this file upload work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one and let me know if it not works

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.className("gwt-FileUpload"));
fileInput.sendKeys("C:/path/to/file.jpg");
```

Comment: List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("gwt-FileUpload"));
                elements.get(1).sendKeys(AbsolutePath);
worked using above code

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will help to solve your issue. But i have not tested yet.

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.name("uploadfile"));
fileInput.sendKeys("C:/path/to/file.jpg");


    (OR)

driver.findElement(By.id("inputFile")).sendKeys("C:/path/to/file.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

@AutoMater - You can update your code as below:

It should work as it is working for me. And give your test method priority as per your requirement. Just for Example I gave priority here as @Test(priority = 1). I hope it should work for you.

```
@Test(priority = 1)
    public void CERTIFICATIONSSCREENUploadCertficationFilesValidation()
            throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

        //Click on File Upload Button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='certificationFile']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // Set the file name in the clipboard. Also following line of code will search file in your computer so make sure you provide correct file path.

        StringSelection s = new StringSelection("C:\\Doc\\CertificationFile.xls");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(s, null);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        Robot robot1 = new Robot();
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List elements = driver.findElements(By.className("gwt-FileUpload"));
elements.get(1).sendKeys(filePath);

It worked using above code.
Thanks @Andersson